# Remove a node from a TreeView

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, treeview

I'm creating a treeview using knockoutJS and I'm having some problems to remove some node from de tree. I don't know why but my function don't check all the tree to find a node, only the first branch. Here is my function to remove a node from de tree.

```js
var ViewModel = function(){
 self = this;
 self.data = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.items);
 
 
 self.removerItem = function(item){
  debugger;
  self.Remover(self.data,item);
 }
 
    self.Remover = function(data,item){
  debugger;
  
  for(i = 0; i < data().length; i++){
   
   if(item.CategoryId == data()[i].CategoryId){
    debugger;
    data.remove(item);
    return;
   }
   else{
    debugger;
        if(data()[i].items() != null && data()[i].items() != undefined && data()[i].items().length > 0)
         arguments.callee(data()[i].items,item);
   
   }
    
  }
 } 
 
}

var data = {
    items: [{
  "CategoryId": 65,
        "name": "MORPHED",
        "items": [{
            "name": "5 Day",
            "items": [{
                "CategoryId": 20,
                "name": "30 day countdown"
            }, {
                "CategoryId": 19,
                "name": "Staffing your program"
            }, {
                "CategoryId": 22,
                "name": "Emergency/Medical Information"
            }, {
                "CategoryId": 18,
                "name": "Promoting your program"
            }, {
                "CategoryId": 21,
                "name": "Week of camp"
            }]
        }, {
   "CategoryId": 245,
            "name": "47 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
   "CategoryId": 222,
            "name": "1/27 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
   "CategoryId": 2222,
            "name": "Age Targeted",
            "items": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "CREATE",
        "items": [{
   "CategoryId": 2567,
            "name": "15 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
   "CategoryId": 22245,
            "name": "4 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
   "CategoryId": 2289787,
            "name": "1/2 Day",
            "items": []
        }]
    }]
};

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>




<ul style="list-style-type:none" data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: data }"></ul>

<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>
  <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; border-radius:0">
   <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: white">
    <a>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>      </a>
    <a data-bind="text: name"></a>
    <a class="pull-right" data-bind="click: $root.removerItem"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
   </div>
   <div  class="panel-body" style="margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0 " >
    <ul style="list-style-type:none" data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: $data.items }"></ul>
   </div>
   
  </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/luizvnasc/680x2koc/) is the same code but in jsfiddle.

Comment: We require something in between the code you've posted here (which is a bit too little to reproduce the issue) and the jsfiddle (which is a bit much, containing things not relevant to the problem). Please try to create a [mcve] and include it *in the question itself*, so we can easily help you *and* the question will remain useful to future visitors with the same issue even if the links / external resources rot.

Comment: @Jeroen Sorry, I think now it's better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post has a repro, that's good, but there's still a lot of things going on making it hard to understand, amongst which:

- All sorts of styling and bootstrap stuff irrelevant to the question;
- Way more data (both items and their properties) than needed for the issue;
- A lot of awkward spacing making the code hard to read;
- Littered with `debugger` statements;

Apart from that, a few code-review-ish remarks:

- You don't use `var` with `self` so it's an implicit global;
- IMHO you're overcomplicating things with `arguments.callee` and whatnot, just use the built in `indexOf` and `remove` method;
- You're complicating things by having `self.data`, which is in fact a list of items, and then name the same thing `items` by virtue of using `ko.mapping`.
- You're exposing the `Remover` which can be a private function;
- You're using a capitalized (so constructor function is implied) noun ("Remover") whereas a lowercase verb ("remove") would make more sense.

Here's something that works, with all of the above changed / fixed:

```js
var ViewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.items);

  self.removeItem = function(toDeleteItem) {
    remove(toDeleteItem, self.items);
  }

  function remove(toDeleteItem, itemsObsArray) {
    if (!itemsObsArray) { return false; }
    
    if (itemsObsArray().indexOf(toDeleteItem) >= 0) {
      itemsObsArray.remove(toDeleteItem);
      return true;
    } else {
      var items = itemsObsArray();
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (!!remove(toDeleteItem, items[i].items)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    
    return false;
  }
}

var data = {
  items: [
    {
      "name": "MORPHED",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "5 Day",
          "items": [
            { "name": "30 day countdown" }, 
            { "name": "Staffing your program"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "47 Day",
          "items": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "CREATE",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "15 Day",
          "items": []
        }, {
      "name": "4 Day",
      "items": []
    }]
  }]
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: items }"></ul>

<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html">
  <li>
    <div>
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeItem">remove</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: $data.items }"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</script>
```